# PHP foreach() function and <input /> function for MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, database

I am new to php and mysql. I'm trying to combine both of this code together

```
<?php
foreach( $products as $id => $info )
?>

<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 75px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['id'] : $products[$first_key]['id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['name']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 50px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['name'] : $products[$first_key]['weight']; ?>" /></td>
```

I want to list all the product currently in database. Currently, it only shows data from the first row of database. I did some research and suppose to use 'echo'. I'm stuck. Please help me.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you everyone for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot `{}` here around `foreach` loop

```
<?php
foreach( $products as $id => $info ) {
?>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 75px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['id'] : $products[$first_key]['id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['name']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 50px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['name'] : $products[$first_key]['weight']; ?>" /></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @user1754822 Yeah..:) And don't forgot to accept the answer after your problem is solved...:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix what you already have by including your html in a block:

```
<?php
foreach( $products as $id => $info ) { //<-- starts a foreach block. otherwise it repeats the next statement, whatever that is.
?>

<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 75px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['id'] : $products[$first_key]['id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['name']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 50px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['name'] : $products[$first_key]['weight']; ?>" /></td>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach( $products as $id => $info )
{
?>

<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-width: 75px;" value="<?php echo isset( $id ) ? $products[$id]['id'] : $products[$first_key]['id']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $info['name']; ?>" class="txt" style="max-
...
<?php
}
?>
```

your code is missing the curly braces , I just modified it in my code